# redirect_to object in admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

In Rails you can pass an object to `redirect_to` if you've declared it as a resource in your routes:

```
redirect_to @post
```

I have a polymorphic object `Attachment` that belongs to an owner. `@attachment.owner` could be any object. I need to redirect to the attachment's owner, but both attachment and its owner are resources within an admin namespace:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :attachments, :posts, :comments #etc
end
```

If I knew the `@attachment.owner` was a post, I could `redirect_to admin_post_path(@attachment.owner)`, but since it could be any object, how to I do the redirect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`polymorphic_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_path)

```
polymorphic_path([:admin, @attachment.owner])
```

Comment: `redirect_to [:admin, @attachment.owner]` did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

redirect_to will take a symbol as a parameter. Define a private method with the same name and evaluate the url in that method.

```
redirect_to :my_owner

private

define my_owner
  <evaluate the path here>
end
```

Comment: My goal is to -not- evaluate the path myself.